I get this error when I try pushing files to GitHub
This worked before, but now whatever I do this error comes up and I can't push stuff, I just export zip then upload it there to "push".
Any solutions to this?
App is SPCK, I don't have access to git console.
Tried to push files, gave me this error:
picture of error
It should just push fine because it has worked before, but it seems to have this now.

Did someone made another push to the remote while you are working on the local repo?
$ git fetch origin

$ git merge origin YOUR_BRANCH_NAME

Or simply git pullto get remote repo to your local and merge them with your local changes.
EDIT:As you don't have console access you should check if your app has a pull feature.this should work the same way as cmdlines.
